# Validar Lista de radium buttons com Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, angularjs

Tenho uma lista de campos radium buttons e preciso controlar pelo angular: Validações: uma opção por vez e exibir mensagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Codigo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
  <label>1. As imagens estão legíveis?</label><br class="clear">
  <div class="btn-option">
    <input class="bt-yes" type="radio" id="legivelsim" name="legivelsim" value="true" ng-model="checklist.passo" ng-click="adicionar(checklist.passo)">
    <label class="bt-yes" for="legivelsim">SIM</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-option">
    <input class="bt-no" type="radio" id="legivelnao" name="legivelnao" value="false" ng-model="checklist.passo" ng-click="adicionar(checklist.passo)">
    <label class="bt-no" for="legivelnao">NÃO</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>2. Documento de Identificação está na  <a>Política de Documentos</a> ?</label><br class="clear">
  <div class="btn-option">
    <input class="bt-yes" type="radio" id="docsim" name="docsim" value="true" ng-model="checklist.passo" ng-click="adicionar(checklist.passo)">
    <label class="bt-yes" for="bt2">SIM</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-option">
    <input class="bt-no" type="radio" id="docnao" name="docnao" value="false" ng-model="checklist.passo" ng-click="adicionar(checklist.passo)">
    <label class="bt-no" for="btn2">NÃO</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>3. Documento de Identificação  está dentro do prazo de validade?  Dúvida na análise documental? <a>Clique Aqui.</a></label><br class="clear">
  <div class="btn-option">
    <input class="bt-yes" type="radio" id="validadesim" name="validadesim" value="true" ng-model="checklist.passo" ng-click="adicionar(checklist.passo)">
    <label class="bt-yes" for="bt3">SIM</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-option">
    <input class="bt-no" type="radio" id="validadenao" name="validadenao" value="false" ng-model="checklist.passo" ng-click="adicionar(checklist.passo)">
    <label class="bt-no" for="btn3">NÃO</label>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa fazer algumas alterações no seu `HTML` onde o grupo de `<input type="radio" />` devem [possuir o mesmo nome](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio), a lógica fica no [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) para que tenha um controle da aplicação.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.checklist = {
        pergunta1: false,
        pergunta2: false,
        pergunta3: false
      };

      $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.checklist);
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <label>1. As imagens estão legíveis?</label>
    <br class="clear">
    <div class="btn-option">
      <input class="bt-yes" type="radio" id="p0a" name="p0" value="true" ng-model="checklist.pergunta1" ng-checked="checklist.pergunta1">
      <label class="bt-yes" for="p0a">SIM</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-option">
      <input class="bt-no" type="radio" id="p0b" name="p0" value="false" ng-model="checklist.pergunta1" ng-checked="!checklist.pergunta1">
      <label class="bt-no" for="p0b">NÃO</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>2. Documento de Identificação está na <a>Política de Documentos</a> ?</label>
    <br class="clear">
    <div class="btn-option">
      <input class="bt-yes" type="radio" id="p1a" name="p1" value="true" ng-model="checklist.pergunta2">
      <label class="bt-yes" for="p1a" ng-checked="checklist.pergunta2">SIM</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-option">
      <input class="bt-no" type="radio" id="p1b" name="p1" value="false" ng-model="checklist.pergunta2" ng-checked="!checklist.pergunta2">
      <label class="bt-no" for="p1b">NÃO</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>3. Documento de Identificação está dentro do prazo de validade? Dúvida na análise documental? <a>Clique Aqui.</a>
    </label>
    <br class="clear">
    <div class="btn-option">
      <input class="bt-yes" type="radio" id="p3a" name="p3" value="true" ng-model="checklist.pergunta3" ng-checked="checklist.pergunta3">
      <label class="bt-yes" for="p3a">SIM</label>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-option">
      <input class="bt-no" type="radio" id="p3b" name="p3" value="false" ng-model="checklist.pergunta3" ng-checked="!checklist.pergunta3">
      <label class="bt-no" for="p3b">NÃO</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">Avançar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Como posso pegar o valor imput radio ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva já está no `angular` que é `$scope.checklist` tem os quatro valores verdadeiro e falso, entendeu? como está usando `angular` lá fica os valores!

Comment: var vm = $scope;                                                                    vm.adicionar = function(vm){
       vm.checklist = {
         pergunta1: false,
         pergunta2 : false,
         pergunta3 : false
       };

       vm.submit = function() {
       console.log(vm.checklist);
     };

    };

Comment: Estou recebendo a mensagem: TypeError: Cannot set property 'checklist' of undefined

Comment: `$scope.checklist` seria assim! correto, você não pode usar function(vm) sem passar a variável! @alexjosesilva. O que você deseja fazer com os valores?

Comment: Este é meu cabacelho do controler do angular angular.module('portalvarejistaApp.mesaAnalise').controller('MesaAnalisePropostaController', function ($scope) {
    var vm = $scope;

Comment: @alexjosesilva, OK ... `vm` recebe `$scope` e ? agora fique na dúvida qual é a sua outra dúvida?

Comment: sim...vm recebe $scope

Comment: como eu trato isso dentro do controlador ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva se viu o meu exemplo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53641/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-alexjosesilva).